# Checking Checkboxes by value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to check the checkbox items by looking for its value using JavaScript; I have the below test table with input form. When I put the value id to the form also hitting enter, then checking its checkbox.

For now the JavaScript is checking if value is = 1, but I want to make the value come from the input form to checking specific record.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var chkbox = $('.customcheckbox');
  $(".customvalue").keyup(function() {
    chkbox.prop('checked', this.value == 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="text-center">Checking Checkboxes by Id </h4>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card-md-4">
            <div class="card-body">
              <input id="myTxt" type="text" value="" name="search" class="form-control  ml-auto m-2 customvalue" style="width: 25%;" placeholder="Enter barcode">

              <form action="delete.php" method="post">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        <button type="submit" name="stud_delete_multiple_btn" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete selected?')">DELETE</button>
                      </th>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>First Name</th>
                      <th>Last Name</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

                    <tr>
                      <td style="width: 10px;text-align:center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="stud_id_1" class="customcheckbox" value="1">
                      </td>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td>Susana</td>
                      <td>Daivid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="width: 10px;text-align:center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="stud_id_1" class="customcheckbox" value="2">
                      </td>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>Sose</td>
                      <td>Nawsat</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="width: 10px;text-align:center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="stud_id_1" class="customcheckbox" value="3">
                      </td>
                      <td>3</td>
                      <td>Primso</td>
                      <td>Navid</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="width: 10px;text-align:center">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="stud_id_1" class="customcheckbox" value="4">
                      </td>
                      <td>4</td>
                      <td>Lila</td>
                      <td>Noord</td>
                    </tr>


                  </tbody>

                </table>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    </col-md-12>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: "*I want to make the value come from the input form to checking specific record*" - to clarify, you want to enter the `id` (1, 2, 3, or 4) of a specific entry in your table, and have JavaScript find the table-row with an entry for that id, and check the box? So, if I enter 4 the form should have the last check-box checked? Oh, and also I've converted your code into a running demo, but just wanted to point out that you've got a closing `</col-md-12>` tag (which shouldn't exist), and you seem to be including jQuery twice for some reason. Could you please edit the code to correct the problems?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chkbox = $('.customcheckbox');
    $(".customvalue").keyup(function() {
        const customValue = $(this).val();

        chkbox.each(function() {
            $(this).prop('checked', customValue == $(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well done Dear Faissal, its great now, also i need to press enter to checking checkboxes so i added below, now the problem when i put value and press enter the value still stay in form also when remove it by backspace the checked will back to uncheck $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13){
    var chkbox = $('.customcheckbox');
     
    $(".customvalue").keyup(function() {
        const customValue = $(this).val();
    
        chkbox.each(function() {
            $(this).prop('checked', customValue == $(this).val());
        });
    
    });
}
});

Comment: `js
$(document).ready(function() {
        const chkbox = $('.customcheckbox');
        $(".customvalue").on('keypress', function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13){
                const customValue = $(this).val();

                chkbox.each(function() {
                    $(this).prop('checked', customValue == $(this).val());
                });
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
    });
`